# how can I get good speedup for a parallel write to memory?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm new to OpenMP and trying to get some very basic loops in my code parallelized with OpenMP, with good speedup on multiple cores.  Here's a function in my program:

```
bool Individual::_SetFitnessScaling_1(double source_value, EidosObject **p_values, size_t p_values_size)
{
    if ((source_value < 0.0) || (std::isnan(source_value)))
        return true;
    
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) default(none) shared(p_values_size) firstprivate(p_values, source_value) if(p_values_size >= EIDOS_OMPMIN_SET_FITNESS_S1)
    for (size_t value_index = 0; value_index < p_values_size; ++value_index)
        ((Individual *)(p_values[value_index]))->fitness_scaling_ = source_value;
    
    return false;
}
```

So the goal is to set the `fitnessScaling` ivar of every object pointed to by pointers in the buffer that `p_values` points to, to the same `double` value `source_value`.  Those various objects might be more or less anywhere in memory, so each write probably hits a different cache line; that's an aspect of the code that would be difficult to change, but I'm hoping that by spreading it across multiple cores I can at least divide that pain by a good speedup factor.  The cast to `(Individual *)` is safe, by the way; checks were already done external to this function that guarantee its safety.

You can see my first attempt at parallelizing this, using the default static schedule (so each thread gets its own contiguous block in p_values), making the loop limit `shared`, and making `p_values` and `source_value` be `firstprivate` so each thread gets its own private copy of those variables, initialized to the original value.  The threshold for parallelization, `EIDOS_OMPMIN_SET_FITNESS_S1`, is set to 900.  I test this with a script that passes in a million values, with between 1 and 8 cores (and a max thread count to match), so the loop should certainly run in parallel.  I have followed these same practices in some other places in the code and have seen a good speedup.  [EDIT: I should say that the speedup I observe for this, for 2/4/6/8 cores/threads, is always about 1.1x-1.2x the single-threaded performance, so there's a very small win but it is realized already with 2 cores and does not get any better with 8 cores.]  The notable difference with this code is that this loop spends its time writing to memory; the other loops I have successfully parallelized spend their time doing things like reading values from a buffer and summing across them, so they might be limited by memory read speeds, but not by memory write speeds.

It occurred to me that with all of this writing through a pointer, my loop might be thrashing due to things like aliasing (making the compiler force a flush of the cache after each write), or some such.  I attempted to solve that kind of issue as follows, using `const` and `__restrict`:

```
bool Individual::_SetFitnessScaling_1(double source_value, EidosObject **p_values, size_t p_values_size)
{
    if ((source_value < 0.0) || (std::isnan(source_value)))
        return true;
    
#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(p_values_size) firstprivate(p_values, source_value) if(p_values_size >= EIDOS_OMPMIN_SET_FITNESS_S1)
    {
        EidosObject * const * __restrict local_values = p_values;
        
#pragma omp for schedule(static)
        for (size_t value_index = 0; value_index < p_values_size; ++value_index)
            ((Individual *)(local_values[value_index]))->fitness_scaling_ = source_value;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

This made no difference to the performance, however.  I still suspect that some kind of memory contention, cache thrash, or aliasing issue is preventing the code from parallelizing effectively, but I don't know how to solve it.  Or maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree?

These tests are done with Xcode 13 (i.e., using Apple clang 13.0.0) on macOS, on an M1 Mac mini (2020).

[EDIT: In reply to comments below, a few points.  (1) There is nothing fancy going on inside the class here, no `operator=` or similar; the assignment of `source_value` into `fitness_scaling_` is, in effect, simply the assignment of a double into a field in a struct.  (2) The use of `firstprivate(p_values, source_value)` is to ensure that repeated reading from those values across threads doesn't introduce some kind of between-thread contention that slows things down.  It is recommended in Mattson, He, & Koniges' book "The OpenMP Common Core"; see section 6.3.2, figure 6.10 with the corrected Mandelbrot code using `firstprivate`, and the quote on p. 111: "An easy solution is to change the storage attribute for `eps` to *firstprivate*. This gives each thread its own copy of the variable but with a specified value. Notice that `eps` is read-only. It is not updated inside the parallel region. Therefore, another solution is to let it be shared (`shared(eps)`) or not specify `eps` in a data environment clause and let its default, shared behavior be used. While this would result in correct code, it would potentially increase overhead. If `eps` is shared, every thread will be reading the same address in memory... Some compilers will optimize for such read-only variables by putting them into registers, but we should not rely on that behavior."  I have observed this change speeding up parallelized loops in other contexts, so I have adopted it as my standard practice in such cases; if I have misunderstood, please do let me know.  (3) No, keeping the `fitness_scaling_` values in their own buffer is not a workable solution for several reasons.  Most importantly, this method may be called with any arbitrary buffer of pointers to `Individual`; it is not necessarily setting the `fitness_scaling_` of *all* Individual objects, just an effectively random subset of them, so this operation will never be reducible to a simple `memset()`.  Also, I am going to need to similarly optimize the setting of many other properties on `Individual` and on other classes in my code, so a general solution is needed; I can't very well put all of the ivars of all of my classes into separately allocated buffers external to the objects themselves.  And third, `Individual` objects are being dynamically allocated and deallocated independently of each other, so an external buffer of `fitness_scaling_` values for the objects would have big implementation problems.]

Comment: It is not possible to answer your question without more details about your class definitions. E.g. Is `operator=` defined in your class?  Are you sure that filling up the memory is the bottleneck in your program? My suggestion is to first create a simple example (e.g. filling up an array of int), measure the maximum speedup in your system then move to a more complex one and check when do you loose the speedup. ps: Why do you use `firstprivate(p_values, source_value)`? These values are not changed.

Comment: 3 points: 1/ since your machine only has a single memory controller, don't expect any sort of dramatic speed-up. 2/ as already pointed, you should use `shared` rather than `firstprivate` 3/ couldn't you consider having a continuous array storing your `fitness_scaling` values and only having your `fitness_scaling_` class members pointing to them? This way, their initialization becomes a trivial `memset()` on the whole array.

Comment: Added some replies to comments so far; see the "EDIT:" section added.  @Gilles can you expand on your first point?  This is new information for me.  I thought each core has its own channel to memory (not to mention to cache, but cache will quickly be overwhelmed by this algorithm since the writes are so scattered, so it is the pipe to memory that matters).  Can you point me to something I can read on this topic?  It sounds like it may, indeed, be the reason this doesn't scale well.  (But then is there any solution at all?)

Comment: @Laci filling up an array of int would not really be comparable since then the write addresses would be contiguous; here they are scattered.  The algorithm here actually seems as simple as it can be, for the given problem.  Given a buffer of pointers to locations in memory that can be regarded as uncorrelated and random, write a constant value out to all of those locations.  That's essentially all my code is doing, and the problem cannot, I don't think, be simplified further than that, to something like "filling up an array of int".  But perhaps I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Regarding the memory controller question, this seems useful: https://www.anandtech.com/show/16252/mac-mini-apple-m1-tested.  "the M1 hits a peak of 68.25GB/s memory bandwidth"... "memory copies land in at 60 to 62GB/s"... "The fact that a single Firestorm core can almost saturate the memory controllers is astounding and something we’ve never seen in a design before"... "Because one core is able to make use of almost the whole memory bandwidth, having multiple cores access things at the same time don’t actually increase the system bandwidth".  This does seem to explain things.

Comment: I don't understand the details of this memory controller stuff, but the take-home point seems to be that the M1 chip (different from most CPUs, apparently) can nearly saturate the memory controller with a single core, so additional cores also writing to memory give very limited improvement, and may actually hurt performance.  That's what I'm seeing.  It would be great to get an answer that explains this in more detail, though.  How general is this problem, how common is one vs. multiple memory controllers, and for cross-platform code (like mine) how is this best detected and handled?

Comment: Just to mention yet another factor: since your objects can be dynamically allocated and freed, you have a good chance of overwhelming your TLB. Here's an experiment: first make a `std::vector` of `Individual` objects, and run your timing. They should be fairly close together in memory, so speed up decently. Now run your code after a bunch of free/realloac of individuals has been done. It should be much slower because you're accessing more pages than your TLB can track.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout the objects are allocated out of my own memory pool, not with `new` or `malloc`, so they should at least tend to be one the same memory pages as each other.  The use of the memory pool did indeed improve performance substantially, even in the single-threaded case.  But I haven't encountered the concept of the "TLB" before; I'll read up on that, thanks.

Comment: TLB is not often focused on. It mostly comes into play if you're really dancing around in memory, and most applications are fairly regular. In this case: I have no idea what the size of the TLB is of the Apple processors. Let's call it 256 entries, then it can track 256 x 4k (assuming that's the sizes of small pages) is only 1M of memory. (Let me check my math on that!) Can you set your OS to use "large pages"? That might again give you an improvement. Assuming 1Mb for a large page, that means your pool can be 256Mbyte.

Comment: My remark about the number of controller was more pointing to the fact that having multi-threading improving the performance of a memory-bound problem is usually better achieved on a multi-socket NUMA environment. Indeed, there, the extra thread(s) allow accessing the memory controller attached to the other socket, essentially doubling the potential of memory bandwidth. When you have only one socket, multi-threading can help, but only moderately. Typically, having more threads than the number of memory channels won't give you much, even in the best of circumstances

Comment: @VictorEijkhout According to [this](https://www.anandtech.com/show/16226/apple-silicon-m1-a14-deep-dive/2), the L2 TLB has 3072 pages which is pretty huge. Pages appear to be 16 KiB wide which means 48 MiB covered by the TLB. The L2 is shared between the high-performance cores. This is more than Skylake provides while TLB issues are pretty rare already. Large pages are a good idea but there is sometime less entries for such pages.

Comment: The Apple M1 processor has a huge memory throughput but 1 core can already nearly saturate the RAM so using multiple threads does not help much (unless you are latency bound). To quote [this article](https://www.anandtech.com/show/16252): "*A single Firestorm achieves memory reads up to around 58GB/s, with memory writes coming in at 33-36GB/s. [...] a single Firestorm core can almost saturate the memory controllers [...] having multiple cores access things at the same time don’t actually increase the system bandwidth*". You should compute the throughput to know how good the current code is

Comment: The reason why the M1 is so good for that is that Firestorm cores has a much wider pipeline than usual x86 cores. The memory latency can be easily overlapped thanks to this (assuming your code does not have any loop carried dependency). As for cache trashing, this is indeed very important since the M1 cache are not huge. You should take care of using a small alignment (possibly randomized). Something like 16-64 bytes, not much more, otherwise the cache associativity can cause data to be fetched again and again from the RAM with a much higher latency.

Comment: @bhaller: Just to confirm some basics on modern CPU design: CPU cores generally write to cache, the memory controller sits between cache and main memory. In assembly you can bypass the cache, but C++ compilers typical don't do that. Stuff like TLB's is handled at the cache/memory controller boundary; cache entries ignore TLB.